# Aggregate data with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
df =

date        name      val1     val2
-----------------------------------
14:55:00    name1     1        2
14:55:00    name1     2        4
15:00:00    name2     3        6
15:00:00    name3     4        8
15:05:00    name4     5        10
15:05:00    name5     6        12
```

What I would like to do is aggregate the data if the dates are the same - but only if the name is different. So the above data frame should actually become:

```
df_new =

date        name            val1     val2
-----------------------------------------
15:00:00    name2+name3     7        14
15:05:00    name4+name5     11       22
```

Currently I am almost doing it with:

```
df_new = df.groupby("date", as_index=False).agg({"name" : "+".join, "val1" : "sum", "val2" : "sum"})
```

However, this will also aggregate the ones where the `name` is the same, which it shouldn't. **EDIT: It should also be noted that there are only a few different names. The names will be repeated in each date-interval. It's just that when the dates are aggregated the names can't be the same.**

Can this be fixed ?

Comment: Do you mean to sum the names like that? Are you trying to do `df.groupby(['date','name']).agg({'val1:'sum','val2':'sum'})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the duplicates, drop them, and then aggregate on the date column:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'name'], 
                    keep=False)
   .groupby('date')
   .sum()
  )
 
          val1  val2
date                
15:00:00     7    14
15:05:00    11    22
```

Comment: Maybe I should mention, that the names in general are the same. There are actually only six different names. For each date many of the same names will appear, which they can, there just can't be the same names within the same date. Will this work for that as well ?

Comment: yes it should work. you can always throw it back here if the logic fails. someone from the community can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['date', 'name'], keep=False)]
   .groupby('date', as_index=False)
   .agg({"name" : "+".join, "val1" : "sum", "val2" : "sum"})
)



       date         name  val1  val2
0  15:00:00  name2+name3     7    14
1  15:05:00  name4+name5    11    22
```

Here, we firstly get rid of those entries that we don't want to aggregate:  same date and name.  We still keep the duplicated names if the dates are different.